# Create a curve array along two other curvers

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to draw a car using bezier curves. At the moment I'm working on the car wing. Everything you can see on the following image are curves. I am trying to create an array of the marked curve segment rotating it along the the two other curves it's embedded with. So the result basically looks like the blue lines on the second picture. I have absolutely no clue how to do that. Does anyone of you have an idea? [image]

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with curves in Blender but from what I can see here you want something similar to NURBS modeling and this is really weak feature in Blender. It could be easier to change curves to mesh and fill this shape with faces. You can do this by selecting first two vertices and hitting 'F'.